# Android Library - determine which package is being used

Tags: android, package

I have an Android Library (e.g. libA) that is referenced by two packages, com.siteA.appA and com.siteB.appB.

This works fine, but I want to modify the behaviour of the library based on the package (e.g. appB could display ads).

Is there way I can determine which package is using the Library *from* the library?

E.g. within LibA

```
if(package == "com.siteA.appA"){

   // Don't display adverts

}else{

  // Display adverts.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the package name just use the `Context`:

```
ctx.getPackageName()
```

If you need more info, you will need to use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).